# How to declare Raw Binary/Hex data in ObjC and how to pass it in an argument?

Tags: python, objective-c, ios

**This is what I have in Python:**

```
ourAddr = Binary('\x4c\x6f\x8c')
```

I need to declare it in ObjC then pass it to a python script running on another server.

**This is how I've been trying:**

```
char *addr = "\x4c\x6f\x8c";

NSArray *hex = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithChar: addr], nil];
[waitOnEvent setMethod:@"waitOnEvent" withObjects: hex];
```

But I get the response: "Non-licensed address provided" which leads me to think that it doesnt see the 'addr' variable correctly. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

**I have sent it as as string by doing the following:**

```
NSString *const hex = @"4c6f8c"

NSArray *pass = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:hex, nil];

NSString *server = @"http://192.168.0.x:8080"; 
    XMLRPCRequest *waitOnEvent = [[XMLRPCRequest alloc] initWithHost:[NSURL URLWithString:server]];
    [waitOnEvent setMethod:@"waitOnEvent" withObjects:pass];
```

**And this is what I get from the server when I try to pass that string:**

```
16:23:08:448 INFO     http_server waitOnEvent(4c6f8c, )
16:23:08:470 INFO     http_server 192.168.0.x:52982 - -  "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 458

16:23:08:477 INFO     http_server <?xml version='1.0'?>
<methodResponse>
<fault>
<value><struct>
<member>
<name>faultCode</name>
<value><int>1</int></value>
</member>
<member>
<name>faultString</name>
<value><string>&lt;type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'&gt;:Non-licensed address provided</string></value>
</member>
</struct></value>
</fault>
</methodResponse>
```

Comment: Why can't you just pass the string as-is to Python and let it do the conversion for you?

Comment: I've tried. I get a "Non-licensed address provided" from the python server...

Comment: Can you post code showing how you send it as a string to the Python side? Also, you might want to log the value you get in Python, just to make sure its what you expect.

Comment: Ok, with your edit - I see you don't have the same strings on the Python and ObjC sides. You should change the ObjC side to match exactly and try again. Also, Try storing in your array a C compatible string, by using [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [hex cStringUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding], nil]; Printing out the value you are getting on the Python side will definitely help to narrow the issue down - do you have access to make changes to that code?

Comment: What is different in the strings on either side? Are you saying between the ' char *addr = "\x4c\x6f\x8c" ' and 'NSString *const hex = @"4c6f8c" '?

The ASCII encoding gives me an error of:


UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 48: ordinal not in range(128)

I dont have access to make changes to the python server code. I can post what the python client code is though. Maybe that can narrow it down as to what exactly is supposed to pass to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to send your data as ASCII/UTF-8 encoded hex strings or raw binary data?

If it's the latter, you can do the following (I have used your code accordingly):

```
const char addr[] = {0x4c, 0x6f, 0x8c};
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:addr length:sizeof(addr)];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:data];
[waitOnEvent setMethod:@"waitOnEvent" withObjects:array];
```

Comment: Raw binary was correct. Seems like this method is exactly what I needed. No more error from the Python server. Now I just need to format the incoming string properly. Thanks so much for your help! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Your diagnosis is accurate; per the documentation, [`+numberWithChar:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSNumber/numberWithChar%3a)

> Creates and returns an NSNumber object containing a given value,
>   treating it as a signed char.

So the NSNumber you're creating has a value that comes from the address that your C-style string happens to be allocated and is completely unrelated to the value of your string.

I'm not entirely sure what you want, but I think probably:

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:0x4c6f8c]
```

To give an NSNumber object with from the C hexadecimal primitive 0x4c6f8c, which is 5,009,292 in decimal.

If you wanted to put byte values into an array and read just the total value, you'd have to consider endianness issues because C is relatively low level and Objective-C inherits directly from it. You can use the C function [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/) if you have a C string of digits in any base from 2 to 36 and want to get an integer out of them.